# Find with `-exec` but with a delay

Tags: find

I have this code to optimize image size of all my images inside `/dir` directory:

```
find /dir/ -iregex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\)" -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} \;
```

When I run this code, it consumes a lot of my server CPU. So I am wondering: is it possible to me add a delay between each `exec`? For example, I want 100 miliseconds of delay between each time `exec` is called to every image, this way the CPU does not get very busy.

What would you suggest? My server is running Centos 8.

Comment: Why do you want your CPUs not to get busy? Are you afraid they may get tired :-) or is there maybe some more important task your server is meant to do that shouldn't be delayed by that image trimming activity and all your CPU cores are already close to saturation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also add more commands using more `-exec`s

```
find /dir/ -iregex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\)" -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} \; -exec sleep 0.1 \;
```

But as a general rule, if you want to have it working full but being *nice* to other processes, it's very simple to use nice:

```
nice find /dir/ -iregex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\)" -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} \;
```

Comment: Worked amazing! I am having a hard time making that code run in the background! Would you mind taking a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675911/how-to-run-this-simple-command-in-the-background ?

Answer (score 8):

This is the reason that commands like `nice` and `ionice` were created.

- `nice` can be used to reduce the process CPU priority
- `ionice` can be used to reduce the process IO priority

A combination of these can ensure that your process takes only a small slice of the available processor and IO capability. This example pushes the process  IO into the lowest end of the "best effort" class:

```
ionice -c2 -n7 find...
```

Change `-c2` to `-c3` to ensure your process will only run when the IO subsystem is otherwise idle.

This example drops the processor allowance to a low priority:

```
nice -n12 find...
```

Change `-n12` to `-n19` for the least possible priority.

Combine them for maximum effect:

```
ionice -c2 -n7 nice -n12 find...
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a shell loop with `-exec` option of `find` that runs a for loop running `jpegoptim` for every image file found, with an added delay

```bsh
find /dir/ -iregex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\)" -exec sh -c '
  for file; do jpegoptim --strip-all "$file"; sleep 0.1; done' -- {} +
```

Answer (score 3):

By using `-exec cmd ... {} ';'`, you're running one instance of `cmd` for each file. `jpegoptim` can process more than one file per invocation, so you would avoid your CPUs a lot of work by changing it to `-exec cmd ... {} +`:

```
LC_ALL=C nice find . '(' -name '*.[jJ][pP][gG]' -o -name '*.[jJ][pP][eE][gG]' ')' \
  -type f -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} +
```

(here with the `find` command converted to standard syntax and improved so it matches on *all* filenames that end in `.jpg` or `.jpeg` case insensitively, and restricted to regular files).

`nice` tells the scheduler to prioritize other tasks over the ones that are running `find` or `jpegoptim`. It's a lot more efficient than putting those tasks to `sleep` arbitrarily even when your processors have plenty of time to spare (also consider that it takes some CPU time to execute, load, initialise, etc a `sleep` utility).