# How to run this simple command in the background

Tags: linux, find, nohup

I am having a really hard time trying to run the command below on the background:

```
find /dir -iregex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\)" -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} \; -exec sleep 1 \;
```

I tried adding `nohup` at the beginning with no luck. Also tried adding `&` at the end but no luck. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried using [`screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Overview) command instead? I always prefer it to running in background, especially if the program I'm running has outputs that I would like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the problem, it seems you want to close the output of the script? Try this:

```
nohup find /dir -iregex ".*\.\(jpg\|jpeg\)" -exec jpegoptim --strip-all {} \; -exec sleep 1 \; 0<&- >&- 2>&- &
```

Possible duplicate and more information see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10908325/9008720

It might be handy to create a script do this job, like:

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup "$@" 0<&- >&- 2>&- &
```

Let's call it `o`, so next time you just run `o some command script` to make `some command script` run in the background.

EDIT:

I recently discovered that using `>&- 2>&-` with `xsel` or `mpv` causes some problems, so `>/dev/null 2>&1` might be a better choice. When using `>&-` or `2>&-` with a shell script that contain `xsel -ib`, `xsel -ib` has no effect, but `xclip` doesn't has this problem. Also, `>&- 2>&-` doesn't completely close `mpv` output, while `>/dev/null 2>&1` completely close `mpv` output. I'm not sure the reason behind those problems. I think maybe some programs just don't work well with stdout or stderr closed.